# Which service to run doc2vec on AWS?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, gensim, doc2vec

I would like to find the best hyperparameters for my model, but tuning 6 metaparameters over a total of 486 permutations and 200k documents takes a while. That's why I'm thinking about using the free credits on AWS. Ideally I want to run my script and get a .csv file as ouput.

```
vector_size = [100, 200, 300]
window = [2, 5, 10]
epochs = [10, 20, 30]
count =[2, 5, 10] 
dm = [0,1]
sample = [10e-4, 10e-5, 10e-6 ]
```

The problem is that I've never used AWS and the amount of different services is overwhelming. Can you guys give me a hint which service is suitable for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EC2 is one of the original core services that gives you a virtual system in the cloud, with a variety of CPU/RAM options, to run anything you want. You could, with effort, fire up 468 nodes to train & evaluate each model in parallel, saving aside the results, shutting down each node as soon as its run finishes.

(There might be a newer higher-level service which offers some other sort of assistance with job-management, but EC2 is the original generic node-in-the-cloud.)

Another thought for your meta-optimization:

Overdoing `epochs` shouldn't ever hurt - it'll just be wasteful. So you could just do the big test with your largest value, `epochs=30`, and be fairly confident that the other parameters that are best, with that maxed value, won't improve much with fewer `epochs`.

(But, especially if you need to re-run the job often, 30 might only be marginally better than some smaller epochs count - so you could then separately run a test to balance time/cost and evaluation quality.)

Comment: I already accepted the answer but I have one further question. How do I make sure to use the fast version of Doc2Vec on an ec2 instance?

Comment: If you're watching logs, Gensim gives a warning if its optimized code isn't running. You'd also likely notice things going 100x slower, either in progress logging at the INFO level, or just in any test runs, if the fast code isn't installed. (Also, I believe the latest Gensim versions simply fail if the optimized code isn't available, as the undermaintained pure-Python code has been removed.)